# python gets stuck when importing scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm learning to use scapy and while it works fine in the interpreter, I'm having trouble creating .py files using it. Whenever I try to use

```
from scapy.all import *
```

The program gets stuck and gives the fallowing warning:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
```

I've tried to just hide the warnings as suggested in previous answers to similar questions using:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

But when I do so the code still gets stuck on the import line without showing the warning. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

+added comment explaining why this question is not a duplicate

Comment: Why do you want to import the entire library and not just exactly the things you use?

Comment: All the tutorials I've looked at have simply imported the entire class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python(2.7) keeps crashing when launching scapy via console or importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926728/python2-7-keeps-crashing-when-launching-scapy-via-console-or-importing-it)

Comment: the problem that user was experiencing is different than mine since his scapy wouldn't work from the console and mine does

Comment: what os are you using and how much ram is available? `scapy.all` is pretty big

Comment: I'm running windows 10 and I usually have around  2-3 GBs of ram available

Comment: Try to use `from scapy import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this problem in the past, try launching your Python files from the cmd window and not with PyCharm.

In case you don't know how to do that:

`Open file location > Shift + Right click > Choose "open command window here" > type "python **file name**"`

Would have put this suggestion in a comment but I don't have enough rep for that.